# Post form to a different controller action in mvc app hosted in microsoft azure

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a simple form that posts to a different controller action, on the my development machine it works fine, however after publishing the app to Microsoft azure app service it blow up with the following error

```
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
```

```html
<form action="/Contractors/MyTasks/EditTaskCompletionTaskSheet/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            &nbsp;
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="ContractorNotes">Notes</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8">
                                    <textarea id="ContractorNotes" name="ContractorNotes" class="form-control" style="width: 100%; height: 130px;"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="ContractorAttachments">Attachments</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input type="file" id="ContractorAttachments" name="ContractorAttachments" multiple="multiple"
                                           accept=".csv, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel, .pdf, .doc, .docx" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 text-left">
                                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="rounded-button" type="button">Close</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 text-left sm-text-right">
                                <input type="submit" id="EditfinishTaskButton value="SaveChanges" class="rounded-button rounded-green" />
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </form>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It is possible to use the default route rather the custom one?

Comment: Contractors is the name of your area?

Comment: Yes contractors is the name of the area, and I'm in the same area, just another action in another controller.

Comment: if you try a simple controller outside this area, it will work?

Comment: Nope not working the same problem.

Comment: Are you using ASPNET Core? Did you try a redeployment?

Comment: Strangely the problem got fixed without any modification, it looks like it was an IIS configuration issue.